# How does one pronounce /oʊ/ in /oʊvərˈsiz/ in American English?

Tags: pronunciation, american-english, ipa, diphthongs

Today when I checked the Oxford American Dictionary for the pronunciation of *overseas*, I got this in IPA: `/oʊvərˈsiz/`.

According to my understanding, the `/ʊ/` phoneme is pronounced *o* or something like *put*, so the pronunciation of this word would be very difficult, or even meaningless.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pronounciation of w at the end of a word - and what does ʊ mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238099/pronounciation-of-w-at-the-end-of-a-word-and-what-does-%ca%8a-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/oʊ/` dipthong is the one heard in most American pronunciations of the GOAT lexical set, so also in words like *no, toe, tone, so, sew, boat, soap, tow, soul, sold, roll, cold, folk, polka*.

In some speakers, the `/ʊ/` rounding may be less noticeable in non-terminals like *soap* than in terminals like *sew*.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects) for a very basic treatment.

See [here](http://www.soundcomparisons.com/) for a rather more elaborate one.

At first I was confused by your `/oʊvərˈsiz/`, and so thought that the IPA you were looking for is `[ˈoʊvɚˌsaɪz]`.  It might have been clearer to me personally, and more quickly, if you had written `[ˌoʊvɚˈsiːz]`, but you did nothing wrong.

Comment: thank you but i get the IPA from here :http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/overseas   do you think it is some type of mistake in that dictionary?

Comment: @CoderInNetwork No, it's not wrong.  They no longer mark secondary stress at Oxford, at least on this sort of word.  And apparently they aren't marking the length either, which surprises me a bit, but I suppose could be argued to be a phonologic distinction rather than a phonemic one in this case. As for `ər` vs `əɹ` vs `ɚ`, that is just a style difference. For example, IPA `r` is a different sound than `ɹ`, but English makes no phonemic distinction there, so it doesn't matter with /phonemic/ transcriptions instead of [phonologic] ones.